# c++ get Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId

Tags: c++, windows

In c# we can get Current user process id by using this method  in Windows `Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId;`

how can we do this in c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [GetCurrentProcessID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the current process ID, and then call [ProcessIDToSessionID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382990(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert that process ID to a session ID.

Comment: hey thanks for helping.. i am new in QT c++.. how can we do this in QT ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why using QT would make any difference. The functions I mentioned will work just as well.